# Ruby PG Submitted SQL

Tags: sql, ruby, pg

I'm looking for a `PG` method that returns the actual submitted SQL query to the database.  I have this `params` statement sent to the database:

```
resclose = conn.exec_params( %q{ SELECT * FROM alpha WHERE alpha.pname ILIKE $1 ORDER BY id}, [submitted] )
```

This is a simple query with one parameter called `submitted`. Some of my other statements are much more complex.  I'd like to test the actual `SQL` statement in a database client to see that I'm getting what I'm thinking I'm asking for.

Does `PG` have a method that I can use?  I can't seem to find anything that returns the actual query.

Note:  `PG` is a gem, not meant to be `postgresql`.  [PG is here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection)

Comment: It's unclear why you need this.  There is no exact postgres method for what it sounds like you're trying to accomplish.  Can you give an example of the more complex query?  Are you testing Ruby or SQL code?  Either way you should write proper unit tests.

Comment: Not Postgres.  PG.  PG is a gem.  Giving PG the base SQL, with parameters, I would like to somehow obtain the fully structured SQL passed to postgresql.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for explain method? For example: `User.where('id >= :id1 AND id <= :id2', id1: 1, id2:3).explain`

Comment: @iGian Nope.  I know that in other packages, but nothing shows up in PG.  Have a look at the link I added under Note: above.

Comment: You your self are submitting the exact SQL statement that PG is receiving, what else do you want to see?

Comment: There is no way because the `conn.exec_params` is a native C implementation, and the returned object `PG::Result` also has no way to show the SQL. If you really want to see the query that much you can turn on statement logging in your postgress configuration and have a look at it.

Comment: @iGian `.explain` method is provided by ActiveRecord, not PG, although it's not a bad idea for this use case.

Comment: @DiegoSalazar I want to see how the query plays out, exactly how the .explain method delivers.  With complex queries and parameters that can get confusing, it would be nice to get the end resulting query exactly as it's perceived.  Even if `Postgresql` can return it and it's hidden in a `PG` method, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way because the `conn.exec_params` is a native C implementation, and the returned object `PG::Resul`t also has no way to show the SQL. If you really want to see the query you can turn on statement logging in your postgress configuration and have a look at it

You might however try to see if there is some information you might use in the error constants, but you'll have to force an error to get it (note that I changed the name of the table in the query to `alpha_non_existent` to force an error):

```
begin
    resclose = conn.exec_params( %q{ SELECT * FROM alpha_non_existent WHERE pname ILIKE $1 ORDER BY id}, [submitted] )
rescue PG::Error => err
    p [
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_SEVERITY ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_SQLSTATE ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_MESSAGE_PRIMARY ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_MESSAGE_DETAIL ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_MESSAGE_HINT ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_STATEMENT_POSITION ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_INTERNAL_POSITION ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_INTERNAL_QUERY ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_CONTEXT ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_SOURCE_FILE ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_SOURCE_LINE ),
        err.result.error_field( PG::Result::PG_DIAG_SOURCE_FUNCTION ),
    ]
end
```

Comment: Your idea about statement logging is probably where I want to go.  I thought `Postgresql` might have had some method to pass to `PG::Result` so it could be passed to me.  Quite often the case is that I get results, but I want to test the whole transaction, to make sure the results are just not blind results.

Comment: Glad my comment was helpful. I edited the answer to include what I wrote in the comment, so if that is the way you're going please accept the answer as correct.

Comment: I'm trying this, but not there yet.

Comment: Indeed the log does contain not only the statement, but the details of the parameters.  All packaged together nice.  My guess was that `PG` would have had some kind of ability to pass this through.